# How to send Authentication Token in Header using Retrofit 2.0 in android studio

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, retrofit

I want to send agent id and authentication token to API and fetch some related data but it shows me Unauthorized error. I also test API on postman and its working fine.

[Api is working fine in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05OQt.png)

[return response in the android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaOEP.png)

Web service code:

```
 @GET("customerform/showcustomer/{id}")
            Call<GetAllApplicantFormDetailWrapper> GetAllApplicantFormDetail(
                    @Header("Authorization") String access_token, @Path("id") String agent_id);
```

In Activity Api calling code:

```
private void GetAllApplicanntFormList() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.e("TAG_onCheck", agent_id);
            Log.e("TAG_onCheck", sessionManager.GetAgentToken());
            WebServiceFactory.getInstance().GetAllApplicantFormDetail(sessionManager.GetAgentToken().trim(),agent_id)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<GetAllApplicantFormDetailWrapper>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<GetAllApplicantFormDetailWrapper> call, Response<GetAllApplicantFormDetailWrapper> response) {
                          
                            if (response.body() != null) {
                                // JSONObject object = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                                if (response.body().getStatus().equals("1")) {
                                    //  JSONObject responseobj = object.getJSONObject("response");
                                    allapplicantlist.addAll(response.body().getData());
                                    // allapplicantlist.notify();
                                    applicantFormsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
                                } else {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    //                   Snackbar.make(getView(), response.body().getError(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
        
                            if(applicantFormsAdapter.getItemCount()==0){
                                tv_no_record_found.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
        
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<GetAllApplicantFormDetailWrapper> call, Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("TAG_onFailure", t.toString());
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
WebServiceFactory.getInstance().GetAllApplicantFormDetail(sessionManager.GetAgentToken().trim(),agent_id)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<GetAllApplicantFormDetailWrapper>()
```

with

```
WebServiceFactory.getInstance().GetAllApplicantFormDetail("Bearer "+sessionManager.GetAgentToken().trim(),agent_id)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<GetAllApplicantFormDetailWrapper>()
```

This way you can pass the Api Bearer Authorisation tokens in retrofit. Let me know if this one works for you, I have just done `"Bearer " +key`  instead of just `key`

Comment: Still facing the same issue "Unauthorized"